# How do I get the conclusion of the following statements?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

Good morning everyone;
I was doing some math exercises and I came across this problem:

> In the set of real numbers, the operation $\Delta$ is defined as $x \Delta y = x^{2y}$. Consider the following statements:
>
> 1. $\sqrt{2\Delta 1} = 2$
> 2. For the equality $a \Delta b =b$ to be satisfied, the only value of $a$ is $1$.
> 3. The equality $a \Delta b=b \Delta a$ is only satisfied if $a = b$.
>
> Of the above statements, which ones are true?

I have tried to figure out the answer and in the end, I have come to the conclusion that the answer is "B" and "C", but looking at the solver, I have seen that only "A" is the correct answer. does anyone know how to get to the solution?
And... does anyone know how I could research and learn more about this topic?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. Tried to interpret to the best of my ability. You had $x \Delta y = x**y$, what does $**$ mean in this context?

Comment: In (2) is the intent to satisfy for all (b)? and in (3) for all $a,b$?

Comment: @gt6989b I think it's exponentiation. ** Is used in python for example.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee that was my original thought but does not match up well with (2-3)...

Comment: Yeah it satisfies (3) but with additional constraint that they equal 2. We know it's not commutative in full if (3) is false,  and 1 can't be a sole left indentity if (2) is false.

Answer (score 1):

First I think this is more about calculus than logic or set theory. Second I think there are a few ambiguities in the problem, for example $x^{2y}$ is not defined for all real numbers.

1. $\sqrt{2\Delta 1}=\sqrt{2^{2\cdot 1}}=\sqrt{2^2}=\sqrt{4}=2$. Recall that $\sqrt{x}$ means the non-negative square root of (the non-negative number) $x$.
2. Are we looking for an $a$ such that $a\Delta b=b$ holds for all $b$ or holds at least for some $b$? In the former case there is no such $a$, and in the latter case any $0<a\leq 1$ satisfies the requirement. Think about the graph of the function $f(y)=a^{2y}$ and $f(y)=y$; they must intersect somewhere if $0<a\leq 1$. Actually this is true for $0<a\leq e^{1/2e}$; the intuition is that when $a>1$ is very close to $1$, the initial part of $f(y)=a^{2y}$ is almost like a flat line, so it must intersect $f(y)=y$. In any case $1$ is not the only possible value of $a$.
3. $a\Delta b=b\Delta a$ means $a^{2b}=b^{2a}$. There exist different positive numbers $a,b$ that satisfy this equation so $a=b$ is not necessary. Indeed, when $a,b>0$, $a^{2b}=b^{2a}$ is equivalent to $2b\ln a=2a\ln b$ by taking logarithm, which is equivalent to $b/\ln b=a/\ln a$. By routine calculation or using an online grapher such as [GeoGebra](https://www.geogebra.org/calculator), you can see that the equation $x/\ln x=c$ has different solutions $x=a,b$ for some value of $c$.

I think to solve such problems more efficiently, you want to get more familiar with the basic algebraic and graphic properties of functions.

Comment: Operations are defined by sets so it's not wholly misplaced. And properties are relative to relations.